# Use JSON Extractor to extract from a variable NOT a response

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

Is it possible to use the `JSON Extractor` to extract from a JMeter variable, and not directly from a HTTP Response?

Comment: You can upvote answer if it helped

Comment: Tried to do it earlier but I had <10 rep so I couldn't. Done now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to choose `JMeter Variable Name to use` in [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
's `Apply to` field

Make sure variable holds a valid JSON.

[image]

Comment: I've done that and I get this error in the console `JSONPostProcessor: Error processing JSON content in Extract_uri, message: null` I've verified that the JSON is correct. The JSON Path expression is also unchanged from when I extracted directly from a request.

Comment: The response is being initialized into a variable with the following `vars.put("quotesResponse", prev.getResponseDataAsString());`

Comment: The value should be the variable name`quotesResponse`

Comment: What do you mean by 'The value'?

Comment: In Apply to field put value `namequotesResponse`

Comment: Yes I've done that. https://imgur.com/a/thXR7ke (The ${counterA} isn't the issue as if I change that to 0 for example the same error occurs. The expression works when tested through the path tester.

Comment: The documentation states that the JSON Extractor "must be placed as a child of HTTP Sampler or any other sampler that has responses". My JSON Extractor isn't a child of anything that gives a response. That's why I need to extract from a variable.

Comment: Add it under Test Action Sampler

Comment: The extractor doesn't seem to get executed as a child of the Test Action sampler.